# Check Customer and product against order

Tags: magento-1.9, product, customer, sales-order

I want to check the customer and specific product against any order.Like if it exist then i want to show this customer purchased product.I am trying this code but no luck.

```
$orders = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $CustomerId());

$data = $orders->getData();
                echo $data['increment_id'],">>>";
                print_r($data);
               $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID($data[0]['increment_id']);
#get all items
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount= count($items);
$data = array();
$i=0;
#loop for all order items
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
  $data[$i]['name'] = $item->getName();
  $data[$i]['id'] = $item->getProductId();
}
```

As there any way where i can adjust both customer and proudct on same filter.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by `join` of `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_item`  tables

As you get sales_flat_order data using `Mage::getModel("sales/order")->getCollection()` collection then just  join `sales_flat_order_item table` with  this collection.

```
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel("sales/order_collection")
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_id')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('customer_email')
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('increment_id');

                            ;
echo $select = $orders->getSelect()->joinleft(
array('item_table'=>$orders->getTable('sales/order_item')),
    'main_table.entity_id=item_table.order_id',
    array('productid'=>'item_table.product_id','product_name'=>'item_table.name')
);
$data=array();
foreach($orders as $order){

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($order->getData()); echo "</pre>";
    $data[]= array(
        'id' => $order->getProductid(),
        'name' => $order->getProductName(),
        'customer_id' =>$order->getCustomerId()
      );
}
```

Comment: Thanks i got this error result .`Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "176" already exist`.

Comment: ok , i wil check

Comment: resolved........ please check