# How to find order is exist using sku in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

How to find order exists using SKU in Magento 1.9.

SKU is "ABC";

I want to check how many orders are available for the particular product using SKU.

Comment: Please review this 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52314/check-customer-and-product-against-order

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the below code to get the orders for a particular SKU

```
$sku = "ABC";
 $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
           ->getCollection()
           ->join(array('order_item' => 'sales/order_item'),'main_table.entity_id = order_item.order_id');

 $orders->addFieldToFilter('order_item.sku', array(array('like' => '%'.$sku.'%')));
```

Comment: Manashvi Birla : Thank you I will check it. But can you give me any other solutions instead of like query. (gt or et).